# В каком формате хранить описание периодичности в БД?

Tags: php, дата

Пишу систему обработки заявок на PHP. Появилась необходимость конвертировать простые задачи с дедлайном в периодические.

Как я это вижу:
У задачи задается периодичность например "каждую неделю в понедельник", при создании задачи находится дата ближайшего понедельника и этой датой ставится дедлайн. В момент выполнения периодической задачи, определяется дата следующего понедельника и создается новая  задача с новым дедлайном и так далее. То есть в моменте есть только одна открытая задача.

Нужно иметь возможность задавать периодичность гибко, например:

- каждый месяц в первый рабочий день
- каждый месяц в первый понедельник
- каждый месяц 10 и 25 числа
- каждую неделю в понедельник среду и пятницу
- каждые 2 недели в среду
- каждый рабочий день
- каждый год в первый понедельник сентября
- два раза в год в первый рабочий день мая и октября
- и так далее

И так вопрос: в какой форме хранить такие периодичности в базе, а затем парсить их и получать следующую и предыдущую даты наступления события.

*strtotime* для этого недостаточно, если я хочу например дни недели указывать через чекбоксы.

Отсчитывать от начальной даты дни тоже не подходит, потому что период между событиями не постоянный.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно проделать следующее:

1. Собрать ВСЕ возможные в принципе шаблоны - т.е. продолжить список шаблонов так, чтобы впоследствии любой самый дикий график можно было описать одним из шаблонов.
2. Для каждого шаблона задать свой "индекс" и создать процедуру развёртки шаблона в годовой график. Поскольку большинство шаблонов (особенно с совпадающей периодичностью) будут допускать объединение кода (различия незначительны), список можно сделать двухуровневым, и соответственно в процедуру передавать подтип данного типа для учёта минорных особенностей. Результатом работы процедуры должна быть временная таблица графика в памяти.
3. Написать пользовательскую функцию, которая по заданным типу, подтипу, параметрам и заданной дате будет, вызывая процедуру, получать таблицу, выбирать из неё требуемое значение и возвращать его.

Понятно, что это будет почти процедурное программирование - но зато логика уйдёт на сервер, что значительно упростит клиента. К тому же этот код будет из разряда "один раз отладить и навсегда забыть".

Дополнительно по п. 2:

1. Возможно, имеет смысл делать и вторую таблицу, с параметрами, по которым построена первая - эдакое псевдокэширование. С учётом того, что нужно *получать следующую и предыдущую даты наступления события*, это уже будет минимум один ре-юз и, соответственно, экономия.
2. Для удобства можно завести статическую таблицу чисел (от 1 до 366) - в этой БД или в служебной. Чтобы не генерить её каждый раз "на лету".

Comment: Похоже, что так и придется сделать. На самом деле вариантов не так много, если посмотреть интерфейс выставления периодической задачи, который предлагает например Microsoft в Outlook и MS Project, там 4 варианта: _ежегодно_, _ежемесячно_, _еженедельно_, _ежедневно_, каждый из которых делится еще на два, т.е. всего 8 вариантов. И я не смог придумать такой график, который под них бы не подходил. Некоторые системы планирования предлагают еще ежеквартально, но это частный случай _ежемесячного_ с периодом 4.

Comment: _я не смог придумать такой график, который под них бы не подходил._ Не помню, как оно выглядит в аутлуке, но вроде такой график как "последний понедельник месяца" в нём задать не получится.

Comment: в 16-м можно, не знаю как в более старых. Я даже форму эту оттуда позаимствую и под веб перерисую. Отлично они её проработали.

Answer (score 1):

Если использовать \DateTime, то абсолютно не важно, в каком формате хранится дата.
Можно получить дату и время из UNIXTIME или из обычного TIMESTAMP, а потом использовать метод format для вывода даты и времени в необходимом формате. 
С помощью метода add можно изменять дату на N дней, часов, недель, лет, etc...

http://php.net/manual/ru/class.datetime.php
Если все операции с датами будут происходить на уровне БД, то TIMESTAMP или DATE предпочтительнее.

Comment: вопрос не в том, как хранить дату, а в том, как хранить алгоритм для вычисления даты относительно текущей, если можно так выразиться.

Comment: Можно хранить интервалы http://php.net/manual/ru/class.dateinterval.php Зная тип и значение, можно вычислить необходимую дату

Comment: Посмотрите еще в  сторону периодов http://php.net/manual/ru/class.dateperiod.php

Answer (score 1):

Я подобную задачу решал через [cron-маску](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)

```
* * * * * маска
- - - - -
| | | | |
| | | | ----- День недели (0 - 7) (Воскресенье =0 или =7)
| | | ------- Месяц (1 - 12)
| | --------- День (1 - 31)
| ----------- Час (0 - 23)
------------- Минута (0 - 59)
```

Примеры

- каждые 2 недели в среду - `0 12 1-14 * 3`
- каждый год в первый понедельник сентября - `0 12 1-7 9 1`
- два раза в год в первый понедельник мая и октября - `0 12 1-7 5,10 1`

Такой маской нельзя задать понятие "рабочий день"

Для того, чтобы задать всякие извращенные маски можно задавать последовательность масок, с условием, что следующая маска начинается учитывать после того, как сработала предыдущая

- первый понедельник после первого вторника месяца - `0 12 1-7 * 2 | 0 12 1-14 * 1`

Comment: Такая маска не позволяет задать: "каждые 2 недели в среду", "каждый год в первый понедельник сентября", "два раза в год в первый рабочий день мая и октября".

Comment: @Akina Такие идиотские расписания никому и не нужны.

Comment: А, может, ему нужно поздравить кого в САСШ с выборами президента... "первый понедельник после первого вторника месяца"...

Comment: @Sergey под такие идиотские расписания подпадают санитарные дни, инвентаризация, ручные бэкапы, проверки количества расходки, обновления, запрос и выставление счетов на периодические услуги и много чего еще.

Comment: @Akina все она позволяет